# C read from a file descriptor

Tags: c, readfile, file-descriptor

I am trying to use the read function in C.
(This function:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html).
When I read from different files which contains the same contents ('H').
The buffers are not equal after the read functions are being called, but when I am trying to print it in %c format both print 'H' (the correct output).

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>


/* #DEFINES */
#define ADD1 "text1.txt"
#define ADD2 "text2.txt"
#define SIZE 1

int main()
{

    // Initializing
    int fdin1=0,fdin2=0;

    int r1=1,r2=1;
    unsigned char * buff1[SIZE+1];
    unsigned char * buff2[SIZE+1];


    fdin1 = open(ADD1,O_RDONLY);
    if (fdin1 < 0) /* means file open did not take place */
    {
        perror("after open "); /* text explaining why */
        exit(-1);
    }
    fdin2 = open(ADD2,O_RDONLY);
    if (fdin2 < 0) /* means file open did not take place */
    {
        perror("after open "); /* text explaining why */
        exit(-1);
    }


    // Reading the bytes

    r1 = read(fdin1,buff1,SIZE);
    r2 = read(fdin2,buff2,SIZE);

    // after this buff1[0] and buff2[0] does not contain the same value!
    // But, both r1 and r2 equals to 1.

    printf("%c\n",buff1[0]);
    printf("%c\n",buff2[0]);

    // It prints the correct output (both H)

    close(fdin1);
    close(fdin2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why do you thnink they don't contain the same value if they print the same?

Comment: what do you mean by "buffers are not equal"

Comment: Your declarations of `buff1` and `buff2` are wrong. They should be `unsigned char`, not `unsigned char *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define buffers as `unsigned char buff1[SIZE+1]` and `unsigned char buff2[SIZE+1]`. It is not necessary to define array of pointers. BTW, it is not necessary to allocate `SIZE + 1` bytes because `read` does not add zero byte at the end. When you say "buffer is X bytes" it is X bytes. Better use `read(fdin1, buff1, sizeof buff1)`.